# If the area of a rectangle is divisible by $d$, must there exist a tiling of the region by polyominoes of size $d$?

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

If the area of a rectangle is divisible by $d$, must there exist a tiling of the region by polyominoes of size $d$?

It clearly isn't true that, if *d* divides the area of a rectangle, then there must exist a tiling of the rectangle using only a single polyomino of size *d*. (Counterexamples are easy to find; let the area equal five and *d* = 4, for instance.) But, given the same premise, it seems like it may be true that there exists a tiling of the rectangle using some combination of *all* of the various distinct *d*-ominoes. Indeed, intuitively, this feels like a paraphrase of what division means: take one geometrical representation of a quantity, and break it up into divisor quantities, of any possible geometrical configuration (i.e., any polyomino shape.)

Is this valid thinking, or is the rectangle constraint in the aforementioned statement too strong? I.e. -- it is definitely true that there exists some geometrical representation of the dividend that can be broken up into some combination of different geometrical representations of the divisor (by definition of division), but we can't be sure that a rectangle is the operative representation of the dividend. If this is the case, counterexamples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fix a positive integer $d$ and suppose you have an $a{\times}b$ rectangle $R$ where $a,b$ are positive integers such that $ab$ is a multiple of $d$.

Let $s=\gcd(a,d)$ and let $t={\large{\frac{d}{s}}}$.

Then we have $st=d$ and $t{\,\mid\,}b$, hence we can write $a=a_1s$ and $b=b_1t$ for some positive integers $a_1,b_1$.

It follows that $R$ can be tiled using $s{\times}t$ rectangular tiles.

Comment: Yeah, I'm realizing this question was poorly phrased. The problem is trivial if you admit the linear polyomino (of dimension $d$ x 1), as your solution assumes you can. I'm going to post another question that gets closer to my inquiry. Thanks for the response, though!

Comment: @GabrielHorn: Tiling with $d{\times}1$ tiles only works if at least one of $a,b$ is a multiple of $d$. For example, if $R$ is a $3{\times}4$ rectangle and $d=6$, tiling $R$ with $6{\times}1$ tiles is clearly not possible, but you _can_ tile $R$ with $2{\times}3$ tiles.

Comment: In that case, then, your solution doesn't work when $d$ is prime.

Comment: @GabrielHorn: Of course it  does. If $d$ is prime, my solution gives a $d{\times}1$ tile.

Comment: Sorry, let me particularize that: if $d$ is prime the tiling consists only of linear polyominos of dimension $d$ x $1$. My point is that your solution needs to assume that you can use these tiles, and if you discount this assumption, it doesn't work. I posted another question that gets more into the geometry of the polyominoes, as I desired to do (but, admittedly, didn't communicate well.)

Comment: But that's the tile my solution gives. And there was no reason to assume such tiles were not allowed.

Comment: Yes, the point of my original comment was simply that your solution depends on including these tiles -- which is not wrong, but not really what I was getting at, as my intention was to think more about tiling geometry. I'm obviously at fault for formulating the question very poorly. The amended question, that tries to assess the relationship between polyomino tiling and division more subtly (without the rectangular tile work-around), can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789170/tiling-a-rectangular-checkerboard-with-one-arbitrary-square-removed